# Are type DocumentReference supported by json_serializable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using json_serializable to generate code. One of my classes has a member variable(legislature) that is of type `DocumentReference` and when I run the generator I get:

```
Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `legislature`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
```

When I remove the legislature  the generator works as expected. Are type `DocumentReference` not supported?

Comment: can you try setting `explicitToJson` property as here https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/explicitToJson.html

Comment: also please see https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/449, may be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Not really - the library is pretty explicit that it only expects to support valid JSON types on the output side.

> valid JSON type such as String, int, or Map<String, dynamic>.

[Source](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html)

However there is a workaround. Although `DocumentReference` is a valid class to pass through to FlutterFire in a `Map<String, object?>` (particularly in combination with `toJson` and `fromJson` arguments to `withConverter` on `DocumentReference` or `CollectionReference` objects, which is probably why you're doing this in the first place!), it is not a valid type for JsonSerializable, which expects only types which can passed directly to json.

A really simple workaround is by extending `JsonConverter` and creating a customer serializer which you then annotate your class with, eg. by placing a `@DocumentSerializer()` annotation.

```
class DocumentSerializer
    implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference, DocumentReference> {
  const DocumentSerializer();

  @override
  DocumentReference fromJson(DocumentReference docRef) => docRef;

  @override
  DocumentReference toJson(DocumentReference docRef) => docRef;
}
```

This then compiles neatly, provided you've not specified a type to the document reference.

Note that due to https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/822 you'll need a seperate class (`implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference?, DocumentReference?>`) if you want to support `DocumentReference?.

Any classes that you've already annotated with `@JsonSerializable()` that use the DocumentReference type will also need to be annotated with `@DocumentSerializer()`, eg.

```
@JsonSerializable()
@DocumentSerializer()
class MyClass {

DocumentReference myDocRef;

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error am I missing something Could not generate `fromJson` code for `recentTrainingRef`.
To support the type `DocumentReference` you can:

Comment: @Almog, i didn't mention you need to annotate the class, i've added an example, that should help

Comment: I did that still get the error you can see my code on here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022764/flutter-json-serializable-using-json-annotation-package-how-to-use-jsonconverter

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong <DocumentReference, DocumentReference> and json from / json to

Comment: You can't send DocumentReference in json not a valid json format

Comment: Well, no. But the question doesn't ask for that - it's about using json_serializable and firebase.

By using the trick in my answer you can force json_serializable to pass a document reference to and from firestore.

Basically a way of forcing json_serializable to return invalid JSON types, deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I want to convert my models toJson and store them in Hive for caching.

Returning docRef from toJson/fromJson fixes the `fromJson` but basically, you're deceiving the `json_serializable` and it breaks the toJson.

**Here's my solution**

When it comes to the `DocumentReference`, you probably only need its path. I'm saving the path and building the ref again from the ref.

```
class DocumentSerializer implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference, String> {
  const DocumentSerializer();

  @override
  DocumentReference fromJson(String path) => _firestore.doc(path);

  @override
  String toJson(DocumentReference docRef) => docRef.path;
}

final _firestore = getIt<FirebaseFirestore>();
```

After that I had to update `fromFirestore` since it really returns `DocumentReference` instead of it's path.

Until more elegant solutions, I'm just changing `DocumentReference` to its path since my fromJson knows what to do for that.

```
  factory AffirmationDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final docRef = data['category_ref'];
    data['category_ref'] = docRef.path;
    return AffirmationDto.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
```

Comment: How do you eventually load the object that the reference points to?