# Flutter JSON serializable using json_annotation package how to use JsonConverter with Firebase Firestore DocumentReference

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save a DocumentReference in models using JSON serializable with a custom JsonConverter but not doing it correct

here is my model

```
@DocumentSerializer()
DocumentReference? recentTrainingRef;
```

My DocumentSerializer Class

```
class DocumentSerializer
    implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference, DocumentReference> {
  const DocumentSerializer();

  @override
  DocumentReference fromJson(DocumentReference docRef) => docRef;

  @override
  DocumentReference toJson(DocumentReference docRef) => docRef;
}
```

I'm getting the following error `Could not generate fromJson code for recentTrainingRef.`

Comment: I'm assuming that DocumentReference is a Firebase class and if so I'm guessing that it's not generating it because DocumentReference probably doesn't have a toJson.

Comment: yea but the whole idea is to save the ref in the backend  flutter side - https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html

Functions side - updateObject.recentTraining = snap.ref; 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Comment: In that case, you only need the id, right?

Comment: @developerextraordinare - you might need the full path (which yes you could pass as a string as well, but I didn't really like the idea of deserializing arbitrary paths from JSON when they're being stored as a first class format).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022764/flutter-json-serializable-using-json-annotation-package-how-to-use-jsonconverter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my answer [Are type DocumentReference supported by json_serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489196/are-type-documentreference-supported-by-json-serializable/70699373#70699373), due to https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/822, you need a nullable document serializer because your type (DocumentReference?) is nullable (because of the `?` at the end).

Quite simply (and you'll need to add @DocumentSerializerNullable() annotation before the class you're trying to use it with).

```
class DocumentSerializerNullable
    implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference?, DocumentReference?> {
  const DocumentSerializerNullable();

  @override
  DocumentReference? fromJson(DocumentReference? docRef) => docRef;

  @override
  DocumentReference? toJson(DocumentReference? docRef) => docRef;
}
```